# Explaining to someone why type casting isn't done automatically at compile time

Tags: c, fortran

Recently, while I was writing a brief introduction to C for Fortran programmers, one of said Fortran programmers asked me about type casting.
To him, it did not really make sense that in C you have to explicitly cast variables instead of having the compiler do it for you automatically.
I actually had a bit of hard time making my point that this is good thing because it helps in avoiding unintentional errors.

How would you justify this?

Comment: Huh? C automatically converts when needed. Casts (as in explicit conversions), in C, are usually wrong anyway.

Comment: @pmg: When i first learned C in college, I was instructed to _never_ leave out the explicit conversion when operating on different data types (quite firmly actually). Why would you say they are wrong?

Comment: The compiler has a better knowledge of the types of the objects. Leave the conversions to it ... and if somehow it can't do the conversion, assume **you** are doing something wrong (like mixing pointers and ints)

Comment: Just wait till you have to justify that C uses row-major rather than column-major storage layout for its arrays.

Comment: @Emanuel Ey: Early C did not have prototypes, and the compiler did not perform nearly as many conversions on your behalf as ANSI C and later do. Function prototypes obviate the need for most of the casts required prior to ANSI C.

Comment: @Jeremy: that makes sense. Nice one about the arrays :D

Comment: @Emanuel: your college C professor was probably someone who wished they were programming in a strongly-typed language, but somehow ended up in C anyway, which is weakly-typed. You can try to enforce a style in which you pretend C is strongly-typed, or you can accept the "opinion" of the language you're using. The problem with the former approach is that without compiler enforcement occasionally you'll let an implicit conversion slip through the net, it's really hard to always remember to write `long x = 0L;` instead of `long x = 0;`, or `void *p = (void*)0;` in case `NULL` has integer type.

Comment: ... furthermore, as pmg says, casts in C often conceal errors. If you're forever casting pointer types, in particular, then it's pretty easy to lose a `const` along the way. Since you have all the prototype-based warnings on, at least you won't make the classic mistake with `malloc` of using a cast to conceal that you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C **does not need** casts. Conversions are mostly done automatically at compile time.

This works and is idiomatic C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    double x;
    int i;

    x = 42;                  /* automatically convert `int` to `double` */
    i = x;                   /* automatically convert `double` to `int` */
    printf("%f\n", i * 1.0); /* automatically convert `int` to `double` */

    printf("%d\n", (int)x);  /* explicit conversion needed */

    return 0;
}
```

Too many casts in a program indicate the programmer was (probably) using a C++ compiler to compile a C source file. Some (many??) uses of casts are just plain wrong.

Comment: @pmg: Just tested something similar myself, and was surprised that it throws no errors... Even when compiling with my usual "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wno-long-long -Wconversion -Wstrict-prototypes". can it be I actually took over someone's silly dogma without testing trying it out myself?   Still, why do it automatically sometimes, but not when calling printf()?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, often I keep forgetting these -features-

Comment: @Emanuel: `printf` requires the cast because the "%d" expects an int. Being a function with a variable argument list, the compiler can't check the types and convert automatically. The same `x` in my example above, can be used in "regular" functions that accept integers: `abs(x) /* convert double to int */`

Comment: @Emanuel: I usually use a few more `-W` options than you, but `-Wconversion` is a bitch! I don't use this one!

Comment: Can you be more clear what you mean by "C does not need casts", given that you describe one of your examples as "explicit conversion needed"? Presumably you mean that one *could* have written `int y = x; printf("%d\n", y);`, and hence the ability to perform explicit conversion is not formally necessary. Just incredibly useful.

Comment: Hmmm @Steve: that may have been a bit of language (english) abuse, just to couter the OP claim that "in C you have to explicitly cast variables instead of having the compiler do it for you automatically" :)

Answer (score 3):

More generally (to pmg's answer) there are times when the type conversion can be done safety and there are times when it cannot.  Also, there are times when it may do something other than what you want.

Type casting is *required* when it may indicate programmer error.  Pointers are a good example of this.  If you have a pointer to a character and assign it to a pointer to an integer, there might be good reasons to do this, but if done accidentally, you could well get bus errors or invalid results when you dereference that pointer (also, on some very old platforms, the sizes of the pointers were different!).

There are extensive rules on when automatic type conversion happens and how it happens.  Some people would rather cast everything than learn the rules, to ensure that nothing undesired happens.

Comment: _There are extensive rules on when automatic type conversion happens and how it happens._ Can you back that with a link?

Comment: @Emanuel Ey: Section 6.3 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: @John: actually I already have that file on disk :) thanks, that's an informative read.